# Keep getting a white cloudy spot on my phone screen

Tags: lumia, 8.1

On the top right hand side of my screen, every so often I’ll get this white cloudy spot on my phone.  I don’t think it’s a stuck pixel because it’s cloudy and it doesn't appear to be a single pixel.  It also always goes away and comes back and it’s in the exact same spot.

My phone is a Nokia Lumia 1520.

It's really hard to describe what it looks like.  Anyone else having this issue?

**** Edit 1 ****

Here is the spot I was talking about.  It's kind of hard to see in the picture but I think you can get the idea.  This picture was taken using IE with a blank page.  I've also noticed it with other apps too.

The weird thing is I will sometimes see it with one app but IE won't show it but other times IE will show it.  Like right now I see the spot in IE but the WP start page doesn't show it.

I've also seen it with different color backgrounds, over pictures and everything else!

One image show me circling the phenomenon and one where i'm not.

[image: Circling the phenomenon]

[image: Not circling the phenomenon]

Comment: Is it always in the same position? does it line up with something that would previously have been bright in that area (such as a tile, or something like that)? Can you photograph the phenomenon?

Comment: Yes, always in same position. No, it doesn't appear anything bright was in that spot. In that spot on my home page, it's where IE is as a small tile with a purple transparent background.  I can monitor apps to see if any apps are bright that I don't realize.  Next time it happens and I'm near a camera, I'll take a picture.

Comment: It is shown if you change the theme to white and go to some place like settings or app list?

Comment: Right now my settings are on dark theme.  If I go to "start + theme" it doesn't show on "start + theme" with dark theme.  However once I switch it to light theme, I can see it on "start + theme".  I have seen it on dark themes before, for example when I play it in 2048 I use to always see it.  I also use to see it on the App list.  However for the last week or two haven't seen on the dark themes, even when playing 2048.

Comment: Have you got the solution yet? I'm having the ae problem with my Microsoft Lumia 535. Please reply.

Comment: I ended up contacting Nokia/Microsoft and they replaced the devise.

Comment: here's a fix for lcd monitors http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/diy-easily-fix-white-pressure-marks-blotches-clouds-mura-bright-spots-on-your-lcd-led-panel-screen.764051/ . try it at your own risk. but i don't know  how to fix it for mobile screen.

Comment: Dear Michael and Ravimallya, Thanks a lot for the reply. Well, actually what's the White Spot is? If I leave the same as it is will that harm the phone? Please answer in details.

Comment: I don't think it will harm your phone.